# .NET Guitar Chord Library

Tags: .net, music-notation

I'm wondering if there are any .NET libraries (ideally open-source) that deal with guitar chords (e.g. given either a chord or a set of fret/string combinations it can retrieve the corresponding fret/string combination or chord respectively).

I'm having some trouble searching because "C#" is a note and there is a concept of "programming" musically as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you're actually asking for a collection of digitized guitar chords, rather than a particular library. I think that if you look for a guitar chord database, you will find several downloadable programs that incorporate a database, but I haven't found a freely available db of chords yet.  Unfortunately [freebase](http://www.freebase.com/domain/views/music) doesn't seem to include chords.

It may be that all chords are calculable based on a breakdown of their names. In that case you would want a library, or at least the formula, instead of a db. But I don't believe this is the case. There is some explanation of the naming [here](http://www.daccordmusic.com/helps/guitardictionary/cifrasframe.html) though.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it is hard to find something. I looked on sourceforge.net and only found a non active project called [chorderator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/chorderator/) written in c#. The screenshots look nice, but I couldn't get the program to run on my system. Probably need to have Visual Studio installed or something. Hopefully you have better luck. In any case, there seems to be many chord generators on the web and sourceforge, not necessarily in c#, but something you could probably hack into c#.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try SourceForge and see what I can convert to C# :-)  It's a good start at least (no idea why I checked CodeProject but not SourceForge)

Answer (score 1):

Here is [something done with Silverlight](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/using-silverlight-to-build-a-guitar-chord-calculator/) and its on CodePlex.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks I saw that but it seemed a bit narrow for my needs.

Comment: It seems like this solution uses a bunch of .png images to show individual chords. I expected it would have a list of notes and then render them programmatically. Especially since the OP really needs to get a set of notes from the library.

Comment: It's not easy to generate chords programatically. Technically, there are many, many ways to play a C maj chord, but most of them are either unused (say, above the 12th fret) or incredibly awkward, physically speaking. I'd think that the best we can do is a data set of known guitar chords and the OP can render in whichever way he wants. Sadly, don't know of such a data set.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is a fairly old thread, but...

Check out Chordious at http://chordious.com the source code is available and is written in C#.

I used the core DLL from the application to build an MVC version of the chord finder from Chordious.  Feel free to take a look at that if you'd like at http://chordiousweb.gear.host